# Lattice orders and number of elements in a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

My discrete mathematics lecture notes give the following definition of a lattice order:

A 'Partial order R is a lattice order if the set of lower bounds for any two elements $x, y ∈ X$ has the maximum element and the set of upper bounds for any two elements $x, y ∈ X$ has the minimum element.'

I assumed that $x, y$ must be distinct, especially after having looked at the following [definition of a lattice-ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) and noted that a set is a collection of distinct objects.
However, my lecturer holds to his claim that the elements $x, y$ above do not have to be distinct.

Is this possible - i.e., is it possible for $x, y$ in the definition above to be the same?

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y$ the set of lower bounds is $L_x=\{z\in X: z\le x\}$. Since $x\in L_x$ and $x$ is an upper bound for $L_x$, $x=\max L_x$.

We see that the set of lower bounds of one element has always a maximum; analogously, the set of upper bounds of one element has a minimum. In both cases the max and the min is the element itself.

Imposing or not the condition $x\neq y$ in your definition is irrelevant.

Comment: Alright.  I will accept that the two elements can be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Really the thing here to notice is that $x\wedge x=x$ and $x\vee x=x$:

Certainly $x$ is less than or equal to $x$ and so is a lower bound of $\{x\}$. Moreover, if $x<y<x$, we reach a contradiction.  Thus, $x$ is the \emph{greatest} lower bound of $\{x\}$.  Thus, $x\wedge x=\inf\{x,x\}=x$

Analogous reasoning shows that $x$ is the least upper bound of $\{x\}$.  Thus, $x\vee x=\sup\{x,x\}=x$.

Comment: What is the purpose of noticing that $x\wedge x=x$ and $x\vee x=x$?  Also, I think that part of your answer was not emphasised.

Comment: That was what I claimed, and what followed was the proof.  $x\wedge y=\inf\{x,y\}$, while $x\vee y=\sup\{x,y\}$; have you seen this notation before?  Moreover, nothing about lattices was used here; this holds in every poset, not just in lattices.  I.e., there's no reason to specify $x\neq y$ in your definition, because it's going to hold no matter what.

Comment: @CKKOY Not only is there no reason to assume $x\neq y$ in the definition of their infinimum or supremum, but the property $x\vee x=x=x\wedge x$ is usually included (under the name idempotence) when one defines a lattice as a set with two binary operations $\vee$ and $\wedge$ satisfying some axioms.

Comment: @Hayden I have already seen the notation you referred to.  My lecture notes, however, have not covered posets.

Comment: @CKKOY I had assumed you were familiar with posets, given your question defines lattices in terms of posets.  I have edited my answer to be a little more clear about notation and the implications.  Let me know if there's anything that still isn't clear.